# Need help to represent electric field with javascript and canvas

Tags: javascript, physics

Well, im trying to represent electric field, and the problem is that the canvas(arrows) are rotating not what i want.

I have 3 canvas, with position absolute, the green ones are for the green charge(q1) and the blue ones are for the blue charge(q2), canvas3 are the white arrows that represent the resultant electric field

```
        // distanceX and distanceY are the distance between the canvas1(or canvas2 too, because they are in the same exact place) and the charge

        let distanceX = getDistanceBetweenElements(canvas1, x)/100;
        let distanceY = getDistanceBetweenElements(canvas1, y)/100;
        
        //Here im calculating the electric field that is being ejerced in each arrow
        let e1 = (k*q1)/Math.pow(distanceX,2);
        let e2 = (k*q2)/Math.pow(distanceY,2);

        //All of this is to get the postition at center of the charges
        let Q1x = getPositionAtCenter(document.getElementById('x')).x;
        let Q1y = getPositionAtCenter(document.getElementById('x')).y;
        let Q2x = getPositionAtCenter(document.getElementById('y')).x;
        let Q2y = getPositionAtCenter(document.getElementById('y')).y;
        
        const rekt = canvas1.getBoundingClientRect();
        const anchorX= rekt.left + rekt.width / 2;
        const anchorY= rekt.top + rekt.height / 2; 
        
        let angleDeg1 = angle(Q1x, Q1y, anchorX, anchorY);
        let angleDeg2 = angle(Q2x, Q2y, anchorX, anchorY);
        
        //These are the rotation angles depending of is the charge is negative or positive
        let positivo1 = angleDeg1+180;
        let negativo1 = angleDeg1;

        let positivo2 = angleDeg2 + 180;
        let negativo2 = angleDeg2;
```

```
        let angleBetween;
        let anguloResultante;
        if(q1Value && q2Value > 0){
            canvas1.style.transform = `rotate(${positivo1}deg)`;
            canvas2.style.transform = `rotate(${positivo2}deg)`;

            if(positivo1 > positivo2){
                angleBetween = positivo1 - positivo2;
                if(angleBetween > 180){
                    angleBetween = 360 - angleBetween ;
                }

                let alpha = 180 - angleBetween;
                let cosAlpha = Math.cos(alpha)*180/ Math.PI;
                let sinAlpha = Math.sin(alpha)*180/ Math.PI;
                let eR = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e1,2) + Math.pow(e2,2) - 2*e1*e2*cosAlpha)
                anguloResultante = (Math.asin(sinAlpha/eR)*e1) * 180 / Math.PI;
                canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante}deg)`;
            }
            if(positivo2 > positivo1){
                angleBetween = positivo2 - positivo1;
                if(angleBetween > 180){
                    angleBetween = 360 - angleBetween ;
                }

                let alpha = 180 - angleBetween;
                let cosAlpha = Math.cos(alpha)*180/ Math.PI;
                let sinAlpha = Math.sin(alpha)*180/ Math.PI;
                let eR = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e1,2) + Math.pow(e2,2) - 2*e1*e2*cosAlpha)
                anguloResultante = (Math.asin(sinAlpha/eR)*e1) * 180 / Math.PI;
                canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${anguloResultante}deg)`;
            }


        }
```

Comment: You seem to be using angles in degrees, while the functions in `Math` expect radians. Multiply arguments of `Math.sin`, etc. with `Math.PI/180` and the results of `Math.asin`, etc. with `180/Math.PI`

Comment: Math.cos() too?

Comment: Yes, for all direct trigonometric functions `Math.cos`, `Math.sin`, `Math.tan`, etc. you need to convert your degrees to radians (`* Math.PI/180`) and the inverse functions `Math.asin`, `Math.acos`, ... return the results in radians so you probably want to convert them to degrees (`* 180/Math.PI`)

Comment: In the long run, you'll have to just use radians everywhere, as they are the standard for computing trigonometric functions almost universally

Comment: I change it but it's still not working

Comment: You should post the code in such a way that people here can copy - paste it to their environments and debug it (including html if necessary). I think the part you posted there is just not enough for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I just happened to see that you use trig functions with degrees, but otherwise I don't understand what you're doing there...

Comment: can i send you the files to the dm?

Comment: You should make an effort to display it here. It shouldn't be necessary your full code, try to simplify it to just a part that doesn't work (e.g., just one canvas, not all three) but that simplified version should be complete - that is - there should be no functions or variables missing, etc, so it produces an output

Comment: https://mauriciolapi.github.io/proyectoFisica/ open this link, its only work if the two charges are positive, dont put negative values

Comment: It should be `Math.cos(alpha* Math.PI/180)` not `Math.cos(alpha)*180/ Math.PI` everywhere, also with `sin`; the use of `Math.asin` is OK

Comment: Well, that solve something, but still dont work how i want, but its an advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249538/discussion-between-nashe-and-kikon).